# Axler LADR Problem 7C.23 suggestions

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on Sheldon Axler's LADR, and I am working on Problem 23 in section 7C in the Fourth Edition, which states that every inner product on $V$ is of the form $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_T$ for some positive invertible operator $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is a "standard" inner product and $\langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}\rangle_T=\langle T\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}\rangle$.

I don't really know where to start. I've been thinking about converting an arbitrary inner product,  $\langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}\rangle_2$ into a functional representation, fixing one of the vectors. For example, if I fix $\mathbf{u}$, we note $\mathbf{v}\mapsto \langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{u}\rangle_2$ is a linear functional on $V$, so by the Riesz representation, it is equal to $\langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\rangle$ for some vector $\mathbf{w}$. Then my claim is if I have a basis of $V$ say $\mathbf{u}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{u}_n$, then we can define $T$ by $T(\mathbf{u}_i)=\mathbf{w}_i$, where $\mathbf{w}_i$ are the representors.
Now I am having trouble showing that this $T$ is positive (specifically, that it is self-adjoint.) Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Given an inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)$, expand $(u, v)$ by writing $u$ and $v$ in terms of an orthonormal basis for $V$ in the standard inner product.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\cdot, \cdot)$ be another inner product on $V$.

Approach 1 (Brute Force): Let $e_1, \dots, e_n$ be an orthonormal basis of $V$ under $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. Let $u, v \in V$. Then
\begin{align}
(u, v) &= \sum_{i}\sum_{j}u_i\overline{v_j}(e_i, e_j) \\
&= \sum_{j} (\sum_{i}(e_i, e_j)u_i)\overline{v_j}\\
&= \langle Tu, v \rangle 
\end{align}
where $T_{ij} = (e_j, e_i)$. From this we have $\overline{T_{ji}} = T_{ij}$, so $T^* = T$. We have $\langle Tu, u \rangle = (u, u)$, so $T$ is positive-definite.

Approach 2 (your approach): For each $v$, $u \mapsto (u, v)$ is linear, so by Riesz representation, $(u, v) = \langle u, T(v) \rangle$ for some unique vector $T(v) \in V$. It's easy to check that $T : V \to V$ is linear. We have
\begin{align}
\langle u, Tv \rangle &= (u, v) \\ 
&= \overline{(v, u)} \\
&= \overline{\langle v, Tu \rangle} \\
&= \langle Tu, v \rangle.
\end{align}
Thus $T^* = T$. Since $(u, u) = \langle u, Tu \rangle$, $T$ is positive-definite.